# Solr 9 - How can I delete document?

Tags: java, windows, solr, solr9

I'm trying to delete a solr document with the following but it is not being removed from the repository:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/cd1/update?commit=true&stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3E_version_:1743777526692446200%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E`

The response header includes:
`<int name="rf">1</int> <int name="status">0</int>`

- I only have a single node and repository
- I have enabled stream.body in solrconfig.xml but that didn't make any difference.
- I have stopped/started solr

Comment: The request looks ok and should work. Could you please share more information about your schema and solrconfig?

Comment: Thanks. I'm just using the built-in cloud/schemaless schema (I'm new to solr) and the only modification I've made to solrconfig is enabling stream.body and changing the jvm version.